# I tried to use map function for looping my list data in react-hooks useState but I stuck with an error, purposes is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I tried to use map function for looping my list data in react-hooks useState but I stuck with an error, purposes is not defined. I want to show purposes in the dashboard but its not getting showed there.

```
    const UserAccountDetails = props => {
      const { className, userid, user, ...rest } = props;
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [parameters, setParameters] = useState([]);
      // const [user, setUser] = useState({});
      const [open, setopen] = useState(false);
> Here I have defined the states. Its showing that purposes is not defined.
      const [state, changeState]=useState([
        purposes=[" "]
      ])
 > Here I have handled the events 
    const handleEventPurpose = event => {
        const { target } = event;
    
        changeState(state => ({
          ...state,
          eventTitle: target.value
        }));
      };
    
    return (
    <div>
    .....
    
    <Typography
                    gutterBottom
                    color="textSecondary"
                    variant="h6"
                    onChange={handleEventPurpose}
                  >

>Here I am mapping the purposes.But still getting error that purpose is not defined
                    {
                      state.list.map((purpose)=>(
                        <Typography>
                          <p>Purpose: {user.purpose}</p>
                        </Typography>
                      ))
                    }
                    
    
                  </Typography>
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: The `state` variable does seems to have a `list` prop. Hence the error.

Comment: Its showing purposes is not defined

Comment: Did you try state.purposes.map ?

Comment: You've got basic syntax error. `state` is an array, not an object, it doesn't have a `.list` property. Also this: `useState([ purposes=[" "] ])` is just wrong, you're creating an array with a single element, whose value is equal to whatever is returned when you call the operation `purposes=[" "]`, which doesn't return anything as it's just as assignment expression (in this case, trying to assign a non-existent variable "purposes" to an array with a string in it). What sort of data structure are you going for?

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you've declared/defined any `purpose` anywhere in the snippet other than when you try to map `state.list`. As others have pointed out, `state` is an array though, with no `list` property.

Comment: I have removed list but still getting error

Comment: The error i am getting is exactly purposes is not defined

Comment: I cant share the whole code, as its against my company regulation.

Comment: A [Minimal, ***Complete*** and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needn't be any proprietary code, it just needs to be able to reproduce the issue you have. If we can't see the real code, and if we can't see code that reproduces the issue there isn't much we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use state.list property as state is an array not an object.